# Linear combination of roots, field extension and Galois Group

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, solution-verification, galois-theory

Let $p: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. If $p(z) \in F[z]$ and its roots $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n \in E$ such that $F \subseteq E$, then any linear combinations (with coefficients in $F$) of the roots
of $p$ are in $E$.

Proof.

Let the roots of $p$ satisfy, for any $c_i$ in $F$, the following

$$LC := c_1p_1 + c_2p_2 + \ldots + c_np_n$$

Since the roots belong to an extension of $F$, and since the fields are closed under addition, $LC \in E$.

$-----$

I would like to know if the proof is correct (I guess so) and also would like to know what we can say about their Galois Group. The question may seem simple, but I am not so familiar with Galois Theory.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that $p$ belongs to a field? It is a polynomial.

Comment: I guess I corrected. I meant its coefficients. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: That won't be quite right: note that $0$ is a linear combination of any possible set of roots, so $h(x)=x^d$ is possible. Perhaps a one-way containment or implication?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea on what and how the given relation implies something. I'm just familiar with some stuff on vector spaces. Then I thought the roots could be taken as basis for vector spaces, fields and galois groups.

Comment: No, that doesn’t work. For example, if you look at $f(x) = x^2+x+1$, with roots $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\omega^2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, then the roots of $g(x)=x+1$ are all nonzero linear combinations of the roots of $f(x)$, but they clearly have different splitting fields and different Galois groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ArturoMagidin. But what could I conclude then, given such information?

Comment: There is one inclusion that will hold (provided that by “linear combination” you mean “with coefficients in $F$”. It is the *obvious* inclusion.

Comment: That the roots of $h$ are in the same field extension $E$ and galois group of $p$?

Comment: What is $x$? is it an indeterminate? I can't uderstand your question..

Comment: Yes. It is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a field, any linear combination of elements of the field will still be inside the field.
Concerning the galois group of that extension, there is not much we can say, since we dont have a minimality clause for $E$.
Take for instance, the polynomial $p(x)=x^2 +1$ over the rational numbers. The minimal field containing its roots is $\mathbb{Q} [i]$, but E could be any field up to the complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$, provided it contains $\mathbb{Q} [i]$.

EDIT:I made a horrible mistake by calling the integers a field. Corrected the mistake by replacing integers with rational numbers.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, Jason. Thanks for your answer. So, I should specify that $E$ is minimal field? Then the theorem would make some sense? Thanks for clarifying it. Now I see that without a minimality clause for $E$, the theorem doesn't make much sense, since we could say $E = \mathbb{C}$. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. It's a very general statement that does not provide us with enough tools to move forward. If we add that minimality, we get that $E = F(p_1 , p_2 , ... , p_n)$, i.e. the minimal set containing F and the roots of the polynomial, closed for field operations. We can then start calculating the dimension of $E$ when we consider it to be a vector space and so on. There is some merit to not giving the minimality clause, since you can create a sequence of field extensions starting with $F$, and study it. Similar to such a technique, you can look up "Galois theory/ruler and compass problems".

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and time. Now I understand it more clearly! Thanks.